# What is the best strategy for partitioning two tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, partitioning

I want to partition my 2 tables which are `table1(a1,b1)` and `table2(a2,b2)`, where `a1` and `a2` are primary keys of the two tables. So what should be the best strategy for partitioning these two table to support the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.a1 = table2.a2
```

#### ADDITIONAL INFO

And based on that partitioning strategy, I would also want to decide which join can be used to efficiently run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.a1 = table2.b2
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: The query you have offerred is a partial cartesian product - which I'm fairly confident you don't want. Nor do you need to "partition" the data to perform a query with a join (cartesian or not). I suspect you mean something different than "partition". Perhaps you could explain in more detail what you are trying to do and what you expect the benefit of amending the current structure to be.

Comment: @symcbean, I just added some info, hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL `PARTITION` is a special technique for *horizontally* splitting a table based on some key.  This is *not* what you have described.

"Vertical partitioning" is a loosely applied term that is closer to what you seem to be doing.  It refers to having the *columns* of what 'should' be a single table are split across two tables and the tables are linked in a 1:1 relationship.  You have such a relationship via their `PRIMARY KEYs`.

Your query is an example of doing the `JOIN` necessary to get the columns back together.  (@Maxim's reformulation of the query is better; you should use it.)

There is rarely a valid need to vertically partition a table.  Please explain why you want to do it.  We can discuss whether your case warrants it.  Start by providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Inner Join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.a1 = table2.a2;
```

More Info: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Read again, he want partioning to support that query.